# How to define a property as intersection of two "conditions" in OWL2 / Protege / Ontology

Tags: logic, owl, ontology, protege

apologies if the question has already been asked or if the response is trivial. I tried searching for how to implement this specific case but I haven't found any solution.

**PROBLEM: This is what I would like to model:**
Let's imagine that the property *'isFriendOf'* was not symmetric and that in order for this relationship to be possible (x isFriendOf y) the two conditions must be valid:

```
x sendsFriendRequestTo y
y acceptsFriendRequestFrom x
```

And that whenever these two properties are present in our Ontology, then the property *x isFriendOf y* is automatically inferred. That is:

```
(x sendsFriendRequestTo y) AND (y acceptsFriendRequestFrom x) -> x isFriendOf y
```

**What I have tried so far**
I have tried to model this property as a *property chain* in the following ways:

```
1) sendsFriendRequestTo some (acceptsFriendRequestFrom Self) -> isFriendOf
```

(the reasoner gives an error and the log says: *Non-Simple Obj Property is used a simple one*)

```
2) sendsFriendRequestTo o acceptsFriendRequestFrom -> isFriendOf
```

*(although I realize this cannot be the right composition of the two properties)*

**Comments**
I can define Classes as Intersection of two Classes/concepts; but it's not clear to me how to define a property as an intersection of two other properties (and in this case, how to specify domain and range of the final property?).

I found something on *"Rolification"* (i.e., define a Class and then force it to be handled as a Role), but I'm not sure I understood how it works or if it would be useful for the kind of thing I am trying to model.

Any help?

Comment: `sendsFriendRequestTo some (acceptsFriendRequestFrom Self) -> isFriendOf` - that's not a property chain given that the left hand side is a class expression.

Comment: afaik, ``sendsFriendRequestTo(x, y), acceptsFriendRequestFrom(y, x) -> isFriendOf(x, y)`` can't be expressed in OWL 2 DL given that the rule dependency graph contains a cycle, thus, *Description Logic Rules* won't work. But you could simply use an SWRL rule.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for the reply. I will try to use rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OWL, I'm afraid you cannot completely represent this. You can opt for two option: either specify a partial axiomatisation of what you want in OWL, and live with it, or rely on other formalisms. For the case of your specific example, a rule-based framework would suffice (see [AKSW's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595192/how-to-define-a-property-as-intersection-of-two-conditions-in-owl2-protege#comment88203840_50595192)). It is also possible to combine OWL with ad hoc programatic extensions to deal with what OWL cannot express. For instance, if you want to represent the knowledge of physical systems, where numerical values are related according to arithmetic formulas, OWL cannot help you (e.g., the relation between acceleration and external forces). But you can combine an OWL class hierarchy with datatype properties with ad hoc implementation of the physical formulas to cover this case.

OWL alone can cover many use cases in terms of knowledge representation, but in general, it is a fallacy to believe that an ontology will encode all the knowledge that you need for any problem that you face. There must be programming code that takes care of the gaps that the knowledge representation formalism is not able to deal with.

If you have a specific person `ex:p`, you can say who this person is friend with in OWL as follows (in [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) syntax):

```
[ 
  a owl:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty ont:isFriendWith;
  owl:hasValues ex:p
]
    owl:intersectionOf (
      [
        a owl:Restriction;
        owl:onProperty [ owl:inverseOf ont:sendsFriendRequestTo ];
        owl:hasValue ex:p
      ]
      [
        a owl:Restriction; 
        owl:onProperty ont:acceptsFriendRequestFrom;
        owl:hasValue ex:p
      ]
    ) .
```